# How to sed the first/last ocurrence of a row in a CSV?

Tags: bash, csv, sed

Hello I have a CSV file with this random structure

```
,,,,,VALUE1,,,,,VALUE2,,,,
,,VALUE3,,,VALUE4,,,VALUE5,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,VALUE6,,,,VALUE7,,
,,,,,,,,VALUE8,,,,,,
```

And I want to output the first and last ocurrence of each line.

in this manner

For first ocurrence

```
VALUE1
VALUE3
(empty)
VALUE6
VALUE8
```

for last ocurrence

```
VALUE2
VALUE5
(empty)
VALUE7
VALUE8
```

I've searched for hours and didn't find the best way to achieve this.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Thank you everybody, this ,+ as separator is the key.

Comment: It there data between the  `,` like this `a,b,s,VALUE1,d,e` or is it just the `,` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk` with custom field separator:

**First non-empty field:**

```
awk -F ',+' '{print $2}' file
VALUE1
VALUE3

VALUE6
VALUE8
```

**Last non-empty field:**

```
awk -F ',+' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
VALUE2
VALUE5

VALUE7
VALUE8
```

Regex pattern `',+'` will make 1 or more commas as a field separator.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is good for this task

```
perl -F, -lane '@G = grep {$_ ne ""} @F; print $G[0]' file
```

The `grep` command filters out empty fields.
To print the last field, change `$G[0]` to `$G[-1]`

---

With sed:

```
 sed 's/^,*//; s/,.*//' file   # first field
 sed 's/,*$//; s/.*,//' file   # last field
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanr `(empty)` as part of the output.

first:

```
sed '
 s/,*\([^,]\+\).*/\1/;
 s/^,*$/(empty)/;
'
```

last:

```
sed '
 s/\(^\|.*,\)\([^,]\+\),*/\2/;
 s/^,*$/(empty)/;
'
```

Answer (score 0):

From this data:

```
cat file
,,,,,VALUE1,,,,,VALUE2,,,,
,,VALUE3,,,VALUE4,,,VALUE5,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,VALUE6,,,,VALUE7,,
,,,,,,,,VALUE8,,,,,,
```

First occurrence:

```
tr ',' ' ' <file | awk '{print $1}'
VALUE1
VALUE3

VALUE6
VALUE8
```

Last:

```
tr ',' ' ' <file | awk '{print $NF}'
VALUE2
VALUE5

VALUE7
VALUE8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e "s/,*\([^,]*\).*/\1/"
```

should find the first, and

```
sed -e "s/\(,*\([^,][^,]*\)\)*,*/\2/"
```

should find the last.